# How to see the conections in a decoder Quartus II web edition

Tags: quartus, rtl

I have a decoder whos 16 bit output is conecting to a one bit input. Acording to my knowldge of the design it would make sense. How can i know which output port of the decoder is conecting to that input (isSub in the figure)? I already looked at the fan-out in quartus but it doesn't specify it (Fig 2).
If it cannot be done, am i just supposed to asume that the decoder is well implemented and that it just works? (after verifiyng with the testbench)

[image: Fig 1]

[image: Fig 2]

Answer (score 0):

What the RTL viewer shows as a "Decoder" is a simple demultipliexer.

The value of the IN bus indicates which bit is set in the OUT bus. So if you gave a value of `4` to the input, you would get an output of `16'b00000000000010000` (bit [4] is set).

---

To work out which of those 16 bits is connected up to your input pin `isSub`, right click on the pin (the thin wire *outside* the green box), and select "Show Connectivity" (or similar wording). This will tell you what the `isSub` pin is connected to.

You could also right click on the `OUT` pin of the decoder and select the same "Show Connectivity" option to see what each of the sixteen pins are connected to.